# Driving brother's Serbian car in UAE?

Tags: automobiles, uae, serbian-citizens

My brother has a car registered in Serbia. I would like to drive that car in Dubai. I have drivers license issued in Serbia and drivers license issued by UAE on Serbian drivers licence. I have a family visa in UAE.

Comment: Is the car *in* UAE already?

Comment: No, that's the procedure that I have to do first, if it is possible to drive it in UAE.

Answer (score 3):

From this [government website](http://www.dubaicustoms.gov.ae/en/eServices/ServicesForIndividuals/Pages/ClearanceOfPersonalEffects.aspx):

> New and Second Hand Vehicle:
>
> You can import new or used cars according to the import requirements
>   and the following documents need to be provided if the vehicles are
>   brought to the country by a shipping company:
>
> - The invoice
> - The packing list
> - The bill of lading
> - A passport copy (including showing residence permit)
>
> If the cars are imported by persons, the following documents are
>   needed:
>
> - A passport copy (including showing residence permit)
> - The Invoice
>
> The imported vehicles will be checked and evaluated by the customs
>   inspectors and customs tax of 5% will be imposed on the total
>   assessed value of each car.

I fixed two typos ("backing list" and "cares"). I think the biggest issue is that it's not your car. In order to register it in UAE, you likely need to be the owner. You could try with a notarized letter giving you permission from your brother but I don't know if that would be acceptable.

Comment: Note that after you imported the car, you have a UAE car. If you ever want it back in Serbia, you'll need to export/import it again. It only makes sense for a very long stay and/or a very special car.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I plan to drive it for a year or two. I was thinking about driving it on Serbian plates without registering in UAE, since it is already registered. Is that possible?